# How in MVC can I create a template for data on a model but not the entire model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have model that has a lot of repeating data structures. But I want to display groups of related data the same way. For example I have a checkbox next to a text box and if that textbox has been recently edited then an arrow is displayed with it. I don't want to write the same code over and over for the same conditions. Is there a way I can call a view structure and pass in parameters like 3 bools and a string and then it would put them in the correct html display template.

I,m using MVC5, with c#

Answer (score 0):

Sure - you should be able to use Display Templates and Editor Templates.  First, identify what you can abstract out into a stand alone view model.  Based on your question, we can make a stand alone view model with 2 boolean properties and 1 string property.

```
public class PropertyGroup(){
   public bool Checked {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public bool RecentlyEditied{get;set;}
}
```

Create a folder in your Shared views folder called EditorTemplates and place a view inside of that folder named PropertyGroup (whatever the name of your ViewModel class is).  This would be a partial view and look something like

```
@model Core.Models.ViewModels.PropertyGroup
<div>
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.Checked)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Text)
   @if(Model.RecentlyEdited){
       <img src="arrow.gif" />
   }
</div>
```

Now, anyplace that you want that markup to appear, you can do so by called the `Html.EditorFor()` helper and send that ViewModel class.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.PropertyOfTypePropertyGroup)
```

Comment: I am confused, how do I pass my variables to the other view?